# Error 500: No such tax rate, when adding VAT to line items using Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe-related question. I’m using stripe Checkout and need to include the VAT in the receipt for the customer generated by stripe. I created the tax rate in the stripe dashboard and was also able to see “tax created” in the server logs in the terminal. I then copied the tax rate ID from the stripe dashboard into the line items in the stripe checkout session hash. When I tried to test the checkout process i get an 500 error:

> No such tax rate: 'txr_1J0494HS4KRntofdJLdwjrZR'

What seems weird to me is that before there was clearly an interaction with stripe where it stated that the tax rate was created, and now for some weird reason the tax ID is unknown. Has anyone any idea or experience what to do about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this? Getting the same, only difference being that I created the tax rate using the node.js client.